# How to avoid RxJs subscribe callback hell?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm using Angular `RxJs subscribe` to make a `HttpClient` call and then make another call using the values from the first one. In this case, there's a call to get `address object`, and then i make a call using this object. Like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AddressService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getById(addressId: string, userId: string) {
    return this.http.get(BACKEND_URL + 'getAddressById/' + [addressId, userId]);
  }
}
  
export class AddressModalComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private alertService: AlertService, private addressService: AddressService,           @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, private dropdownService: DropdownService)

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addressService.getById(this.data.id, this.data.userId)
        .subscribe(
          (address: Address) => {
            this.dropdownService.getCidadesBrByEstado(address.name)
              .subscribe((cities: BrCity[]) => {
                this.cities = cities;
                this.address = address;
              },
              error => console.log(error));
          }, error => { this.alertService.error(error);
          }
        );
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid multiple Subscribes, there is many like this in my code. I need an `Async/Await` approach like `Node.js promises`, but using Observables at component level. I'm not very familiar with `RxJs commands`... is there a better way to make many calls with just one `subscribe` and `catch`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try something like:

```
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

this.addressService.getById(this.data.id, this.data.userId).pipe(
  switchMap(address => this.dropdownService.getCidadesBrByEstado(address.name).pipe(
    // this pass both cities and address to the next observable in this chain
    map(cities => ({ cities, address }))
  ))
).subscribe(({ cities, address }) => {
  this.cities = cities
  this.address = address
})
```

Comment: whats the difference between `switchMap`, `mergeMap` and `forkJoin`? im not sure if i can `switchMap` every subscription like this

Comment: Operators in RxJS is a very rich API. You have to google/read up on those and try them in simple examples to understand how they work. Not something I can explain in a few words.

Comment: For an explanation of the differences between `switchMap`, `mergeMap`, `concatMap` and `exhaustMap`, have a look at [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/switchmap-bugs-b6de69155524).

Comment: This answer looks just like callback hell. It is just more condensed than the code in the question. Imagine doing this with 4-5 sequential http requests. It would expand as much to the right as it does down with the switchMaps and pipes, and produce typical callback hell visuals.

Comment: Well, `switchMap`, `mergeMap` and `whateverMap` actually solve the problems with readabilty. I see.

Comment: @KristjanLiiva, they won't be _nested_ anymore! See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53861335/4179032) answer for an example with three requests.

Answer (score 6):

For angular when using RxJS, it suggests to use the Observable Class. To solve callback hell in the RxJS, You can use Observable' Operators api like switchMap() method(more methods for different scene are map(), concatMap(), ...). Here is my example about using the switchMap() method:
(1) Situation I met: I want to subsribe serviceC, but serviceC needs subsribe serviceB, and serviceB needs subsribe serviceA

```js
const serviceA(params): Observable<any>;
const serviceB(params): Observable<any>;
const serviceC(params): Observable<any>;

serviceA(paramsA).subscribe(
    serviceAResult => {
        serviceB(paramsB).subscribe(
            serviceBResult => {
                serviceC(params).subscribe(
                    serviceCResult => {
                        // here is my logic code. Oh, Shit subscribe hell!
                    }
                )
            }
        )
    }
)
```

(2) Use switchMap() method to optimize code structure

```js
const serviceB$ = serviceA(paramsA).pipe(
    switchMap(serviceAResult => {
        return serviceB(paramsB);
    })
);

const serviceC$ = serviceB$.pipe(
    switchMap(serviceBResult => {
        return serviceC(paramsC);
    })
);

serviceC$.subscribe(
    serviceCResult => {
        // here is my logic code.
    },
    error =>{
        // handle error
    }
);
```

Good post about dealing with [callback hell](https://academind.com/tutorials/callbacks-vs-promises-vs-rxjs-vs-async-awaits).

Comment: While a link may be handy, it's good to include the essence of the solution here in case that link goes offline or moves.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, you don't actually care about streams you could also convert the Observables to promises in this case and use `async/await`:

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
  this.address = await this.addressService.getById(this.data.id, this.data.userId).toPromise();
  this.cities = await this.dropdownService.getCidadesBrByEstado(this.address.name).toPromise();
}
```

And make sure you also catch the errors. `try catch` for example.