# How could I make 2 different calls and get the 2 responses but united in a single observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, request

What I want to achieve is this: I need to make a call to an endpoint and if it returns data then make the second call and then in the subscribe get the response of both requests. how could i do it?

first attempt failed:

```js
  getInfo(fileNumber: number) {
    concat(
      this.proceedingsService.getActByFileNumber(fileNumber),
      this.detailProceedingsDevolutionService.getDetailProceedingsDevolutionByExpedient(
        fileNumber
      )
    ).subscribe({
      next: data => {
        console.log('--> ', data);
        this.prepareData(data);
      },
      error: error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    });
  }
```

That way I get 2 separate responses (first the one from the first request and then the one from the second), it's as if the subscribe were executed 2 times, which doesn't work for me, I want that when making the subscribe I have the response from both requests only one.

I also tried with the mergeMap but it doesn't work either, since with that operator it only shows me the last response (the one from the second request), and finally I tried with the forkJoin but it doesn't work for me, since with that operator if the first request the second one fails anyway and I don't want that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52415587/how-to-avoid-rxjs-subscribe-callback-hell

Comment: @derstauner you mean using promises? Because as I said in my question, soon the switchMap doesn't do what I want (get the 2 responses from the 2 requests, I only get the response from the last request).

Comment: Please scroll down and look at the acepted answer. And you tried mergemap and not switchmap.

Comment: @derstauner I forgot to mention it, but I did try mergeMap too. I'm still going to check more thoroughly to see if I find something that helps me, thanks.

Comment: Why `forkJoin` doesn’t work?

Comment: @JulianProg, please read the linked accepted answer carefully. It is exactly that, what you want. This is the so called callback hell. First, you call the first request, then you switch to the second request via `switchMap` and pass the returned value from the first request and call the second request with that. And after that with a `map` you can get both results of the two requests.